# Levi-Civita connection

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

Well if $\Sigma$ is a submanifold of $R^{n+p}$ and $\{e_i,e_\alpha\}$ is orthonormal frame over $\Sigma$ where the $e_i$'s are tangent and the $e_\alpha$'s are normal to $\Sigma$.

**Can anyone prove (with an adequate frame) that 
$\nabla_{e_i}^{\perp} e_\alpha=0$?**

**Obs:** The result is pretty easy when we have only one normal direction, but in this case there are more.

Comment: Nobody can prove what is not true in general. Compare this with the [Frenet-Serret formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas).

Comment: The title of the question is quite misleading. The only Levi-Civita connection here is the standard connection in $\Bbb R^n$ whereas $\nabla^{\perp}$ is not the Levi-Civita connection, but a connection in the normal bundle (which is in this case, of course, a part of the ambient L-C connection)

Answer (score 2):

When we have only one normal direction the picture is somewhat simpler than in the general case.

Introduce $h_i{}^\beta{}_\alpha$ by 
$$
\nabla^{\perp}_{e_i}e_{\alpha} = h_i{}^\beta{}_\alpha e_\beta
$$
(Einstein summation assumed), $i=1,\dots,n$, $\alpha, \beta = n+1,\dots,n+p$, as it is assumed in the question.

**Claim.** $h_i{}^\beta{}_\alpha = - h_i{}^\alpha{}_\beta$.

*Proof.* $0 = \nabla_{e_i}\langle e_\alpha , e_\beta \rangle = \langle \nabla^{\perp}_{e_i}e_{\alpha} , e_\beta \rangle + \langle  e_\alpha , \nabla^{\perp}_{e_i}e_{\beta} \rangle = h_i{}_\beta{}_\alpha + h_i{}_\alpha{}_\beta$.

**Corollary.** When $p=1$ (i.e. in the case of hypersurfaces) 
$$
\nabla_{e_i}^{\perp} e_\alpha=0
$$

*Proof.* The only skew-symmetric $1\times1$-matrix is $(0)$.